# How to see closed PR's from GitHub in Visual Studio Code

Tags: github, visual-studio-code

I could integrate my GitHub with Visual Studio Code. I can see all my open PR's and issues in Visual Studio Code.
But my requirement here is that I am not able to see my closed PR's. Is there any solution for this.

I have tried editing `settings.json` with `githubPullRequests.queries` as below.

```
,{
    "label": "Closed PR'S",
    "query": "is:closed mentions:${user}"
}
```

But it is showing 0 pull requests. But I have some closed pull requests that are available in GitHub. Could anyone please suggest other way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is followed by the [GitHub Pull Requests and Issues](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GitHub.vscode-pull-request-github) VSCode extension, and its [`CHANGELOG`](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-pull-request-github/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md).

It includes:

> To customize the pull request tree, you can use the `githubPullRequests.queries` setting.
> This setting is a list of labels and search queries which populate the categories of the tree.
>
> By default, these queries are "`Waiting For My Review`", "`Assigned To Me`", and "`Created By Me`".
> An example of adding a "`Mentioned Me`" category is to change the setting to the following:

```
"githubPullRequests.queries": [
    {
        "label": "Waiting For My Review",
        "query": "is:open review-requested:${user}"
    },
    {
        "label": "Assigned To Me",
        "query": "is:open assignee:${user}"
    },
    {
        "label": "Created By Me",
        "query": "is:open author:${user}"
    },
    {
        "label": "Mentioned Me",
        "query": "is:open mentions:${user}"
    }
]
```

You should be able to add a "my Closed PRs" section.

```
    {
        "label": "My Closed PRs",
        "query": "is:closed assignee:${user}"
    }
```

---

The [OP SASI](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17393387/sasi) reports in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69939654/how-to-see-closed-prs-from-github-in-visual-studio-code/69939783?noredirect=1#comment123640023_69939783):

> Actually I removed `users` and only used `is:closed`

```
    {
        "label": "My Closed PRs",
        "query": "is:closed"
    }
```

Comment: I have already tried this.
        ,{
            "label": "Closed PR'S",
            "query": "is:closed mentions:${user}"
        }
But it is showing 0 pull requests. But I have some closed pull requests that are available in GitHub. Could you please suggest other way

Comment: I tried what you suggest also. But not getting. Can you please suggest

Comment: @SASI Did you try the other options, with `assignee:${user}`, or `author:${user}` or `review-requested:${user}`?

Comment: Great! Actually I removed users and only used `is:closed`. Thanks a lot to get that idea

Comment: @SASI Well done. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: I have gone through it and done

Comment: `is:closed` doesn't work for me. Maybe because I deleted the PR source branch after merging.